# How to use value of one field in the SQL query for list of values of another field on Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have two fields "course" and "unit" in a form. Both are "Select List". There is a junction table "course_unit" in my database which maps courses and their units. Now, I only want to have those units in my "unit" filed that are assigned to the course selected in "course" field. For that I wrote following query and placed it in "SQL Query" inside "List of Values" option for "unit" field

```
SELECT unit_name, unit_id
FROM course_unit
WHERE course_id = :P11_COURSE;
```

This didn't work. I passed a course ID as default value to "course" filed and it worked. Only those units related to the course ID I pass was in the "unit" filed. But changing the course had no effect in "unit" field. I thought this was because every time I select new course the "unit" field wasn't reloading. So I created a dynamic action on "course" field which reloads "unit" field whenever there is any change in "course" field. The "unit" filed is now reloading but still there is no change in values after I select another course. What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy to fix; below the query you wrote is another section named "Cascading list of values" which has one item: **Parent item(s)**. In here, you put item(s) whose value causes select list item's values to change. In your case, it is `P11_COURSE`.

Also, have a look at Help associated to this property, as well as another ones: "Items to submit" and "Parent required" (depending on Apex version you use).